# How to convert String into Array in javaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string like `"[1,2,3]"` and I want to convert it into array like `[1,2,3]` using JavaScript. Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: Is your code snippet alright? It looks like nothing shows up when I run it.

Comment: Do you need those `<br>`? I don't see you are hidding them

Comment: it's because of all the br

Comment: use `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the string you want to convert is compatible to the JSON format (JavaScript object notation), you can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it into an array:

```js
const str = "[1,2,3]";
const arr = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Always glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```js
  var dat = "[1,2,3]";

  var myData = JSON.parse(dat);
  console.log(myData);
```

Comment: Nvm just saw the above answer.